# Communicate to serial over IP rejecting commands MODBUS?

Tags: c#, winforms, sockets, serial-port, modbus

this is a strange one, we have a printer setup with an IP and port it listens in on, we then need to send print jobs to the printer.

I have managed to connect to the printer but when ever I transmit anything I get timeouts on the printer or it just sits there doing nothing.

I know I can talk to the printer as its showing in its logs.

So far I have the following :

```
_Socket = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.IP);
_Socket.Connect("192.168.1.52", 2123);
byte Enq = 0x05;
byte Ack = 0x06;
byte[] tran;
tran = new byte[] { Enq };
_Socket.Send(tran, 1, SocketFlags.None);

tran = new byte[] { 0x30 };
_Socket.Send(tran, 1, SocketFlags.None);

tran = new byte[] { 0x00, 0x01 };
_Socket.Send(tran, 2, SocketFlags.None);

tran = new byte[] { 0xFF };
_Socket.Send(tran, 1, SocketFlags.None);
```

According to the manual I need to do the following :

```
send 1 byte Identifier 30h
send 2 bytes length 00h, 01h
send data (action to be performed) 1 byte FFh
```

as you can probably see I have no idea on how to achieve this so any and all help welcome

```
Edit
```

Some additional information, the printer doesn't come with a driver so from what I can tell I would need to transmit raw data to the printer, the printer has a serial connection to it but its too far away for serial cable hence the Ethernet connection on there (I believe it is serial over Ethernet).

General Principle of Dialog
Computer sends ENQ (1 byte) Printer sends ACK (1 byte)
Computer sends data (Ident 1 byte | length 2 bytes | data 0 to n bytes | Checksum 1 byte)
printer sends Ack (1 byte)

When I've used serial in the past i've used the write function on the port to send the data, get the data into a buffer and once finished receiving check the buffer but I am clueless as to how I would do this onver IP?

```
Identifier (1 hexadecimal byte)
Specific to each command.
 Length (2 hexadecimal bytes)
The length is a hexadecimal value representing the number of bytes present after the
two length bytes and not including the check byte (Checksum).
In general, the maximum value is 2044 bytes or 07h FCh.
For transmission of a message for printing, the maximum value is 4092 bytes or 0Fh
FCh.
Note: The check byte is not checked by the printer if b7 of the first length byte is set
to 1. In this case the data in the frame received is not checked.
Data (0 to n bytes)
Zero bytes for a general request from the computer to the printer.
n bytes representing the instructions needed to define a function.
Checksum (1 hexadecimal byte)
This corresponds to an exclusive OR of all preceding bytes (identifier, length and data
bytes
```

Comment: What does "winforms", "modbus", or "serial-port" have to do with the question? I can see that maybe you have a serial protocol implemented over TCP, and I can imagine that your program might happen to be WinForms based, but where does Modbus come in? I've never heard of a Modbus printer and you certainly aren't implementing the Modbus protocol.

Comment: Why you handle all these low level communication by yourself? And why you call this one as "strange one"?

Comment: @Gabe I beleive it is Modbus with my limited experience however I am uncertain hence the ?

Comment: @DuSijun Because I need to and its a strange one for me

Comment: Why are you sending 0x05 if the manual doesn't mention it? Are you sure the ProtocolType is IP and not TCP? Are you sure the SocketType is Stream and not Dgram? I don't see how anyone could answer this without having the manual themselves.

Comment: @Tergiver 05 is the enquiry and 06 is the acknowledgment, as for the protocol and socket type I have no idea and the manual doesn't meantion which ones to use either, sadly I've read all 120 pages :(

Comment: @Neo I think you're going to have to contact the printer manufacturer to get help.

Comment: What makes you believe it is Modbus? Why don't you tell us what kind of printer it is?

Comment: @Gabe its a Markem Imaje printer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I changed the system to use the TCPClass instead of a socket and it now works as expected, their tech guys were useless but at least their head sales guy came and helped out with what he knows on other problems with the printer, eventually managed to get there.  All boils down to missing information in their documentation